# aggregate anonymous types in linq

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have the below data.

```
 var gradeData = (from data in oAngieCtxt.prc_ShopInstanceCustomersData(Convert.ToInt32(this.ShopInstanceID), 10000, false)
                         .Where(row => row.RecievedPoints != "n/a")
                        .GroupBy(row => new { row.Name })
                        .Select(g => new 
                        {
                            TotalPoints = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.RecievedPoints) * (x.Weightage.ToString() == "0.00" ? 1 : Convert.ToDouble(x.Weightage))),
                            Name = g.Key.Name
                        })
                         select data).ToList();
```

I am assigning this to DataGrid as follows:

```
this.grdAllDealers.DataSource = gradeData;
this.grdAllDealers.DataBind();
```

This will result in screen as

5  A
10 B
15 C
.
.
.
.

However I want this data to printed on screen as 
5 - A
10 - B
15 - C
.
.
.
.

hyphen should come in between TotalPoints and Name.

Can somebody advise how to get this in linq query?

Note: I know to get using foreach, but I want to do it without foreach.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it and it is that simple... may will help future users like me ;)

this.grdAllDealers.DataSource = gradeData.Select(O=> O.TotalPoints + " - " + O.Name );